# "The calling thread..." exception despite usage of Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am developing an WPF application. Without going into details:

```
myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(FILL);
myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(FILL);
```

will cause:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

So obvious fix is:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(FILL);
    myCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(FILL);
}));
```

However, this will still raise an exception:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    myCanvas.Children.Add(eventArgs.getImage());
}));
```

Any ideas why?

edit: I commited full project to: https://riouxsvn.com/svn/kinectfileexplo

Please restrain for commenting code quality = thx ;)

Exception occurs in MainWindow.xaml.cs, Line 54.

Comment: Have you tried accessing myCanvas Dispatcher (if possible)?

Comment: getImage returns image passed to event args. I tried creating brand new Image object there, no difference

Comment: The `Image` control returned by `getImage()` must have been created in the UI thread, i.e. the thread that `this.Dispatcher` is associated to. If it was created in another thread, it can't be added to the Children collection of `myCanvas`.

Answer (score 0):

see if [DispatcherPriority Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) can help

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            myCanvas.Children.Add(eventArgs.getImage());
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: No help ;(

I commited full project to: https://riouxsvn.com/svn/kinectfileexplo

Please restrain for commenting code quality = thx ;)

Comment: @user3623160, I am sorry, I don't have any SVN tools to download your source code